# [Nginx][Gogs] Serving gogs through nginx

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi2, gogs

I'm running through an issue setting up Gogs through Nginx on my raspberry.

I just want to be able to redirect http://raspberry-ip-address:3000 to http://raspberry-ip-address/gogs.

Below my nginx virtualhost conf :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /gogs/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

When I go on http:// raspberry-ip-address:3000, I get the installation page from gogs -> so Gogs is runnning well.

When I go on http:// raspberry-ip-address/gogs, I got a 404 Not found error. however the log from Gogs is somehow "reacting" because I get :

```
[Macaron] 2016-08-24 14:40:30: Started GET /gogs/ for 127.0.0.1
[Macaron] 2016-08-24 14:40:30: Completed /gogs/ 302 Found in 1.795306ms
2016/08/24 14:40:30 [D] Session ID: 8e0bbb6ab5478dde
2016/08/24 14:40:30 [D] CSRF Token: YfL58XxZUDgwim9qBCosC7EXIGM6MTQ3MTk4MDMxMzMxMTQ3MjgzOQ==
```

For more information here is my nginx/error.log :

```
request: "GET /localhost HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.15"
2016/08/24 14:40:30 [error] 3191#0: *4 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/install" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.12, server: localhost, request: "GET /install HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.15"
```

It seems to me that Nginx is not redirecting correctly the request. Any idea ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Does [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite) help you?

Comment: Not really, I tried every answer from this post. 
The set up is working if my nginx conf is like the following :
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }

Comment: So the rewrite does not rewrite the URL? Or does the rewrite happen but somehow gog still gets `/gogs/`? Does it get `/gogs/` even if you put it somewhere else like `/git/`?

Comment: Also the `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;` did also not work?

Comment: After multiple, I found the solution.   `return 301 http://localhost:3000;`

Comment: I used this link to help me https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: That should only work from the machine where gogs runs, it tells the browser to ask again at `localhost:3000`, but localhost is of course different depending on which machine you are asking from. Only the raspberrypi should find there a running gogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following config works:

```
location /gogs/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

but the following (what you posted) produces the error you mentioned:

```
location /gogs/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

note the `/` and the and of the url.

A HTTP redirect (30x) does *not* solve the problem, because it will redirect to `localhost` which is not the raspberry pi but the computer that does the request.

Complete nginx conf in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;


        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /git/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333/;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Could you post me the whole of your nginx conf file ?

Comment: Because indeed you're right. It redirect my request to the computer localhost (and not the Pi)

Comment: If it still doesn't work for you.. I'm on nginx version 1.10.1-1, maybe you have an old version? Did you configure gog somehow to assume the prefix?

Comment: I had a misunderstanding within conf file. Your answer is working. Thanks a lot.